# Use (multiple) results from one query as input for another query

Tags: sql, sql-server, multiple-results

I am writing a ticketing program using Vb.net and SQL

I have 2 tables that I need to use in a query.
One table (Tickets) holds the all values I need.
Second table (Ticketactions) holds all TicketActions linked to a Ticket

What I want is create a search, that searches the following columns:

- Ticket.description
- ticket.ticketID
- Ticketaction.ActionDescrition

I have a search that works well and searches the Tickets Table

```
        SELECT 
    tickets.TicketNumber, 
    tickets.Description,
    tickets.departmentname,
    tickets.devicename,
    tickets.creatorname,
    tickets.creationdate,
    tickets.ExecutionDate,
    tickets.closedate
    stateName,
    PriorityName,
    FullName,
         FROM tickets
    INNER Join Users On Tickets.AssignedTo = Users.UserID
    INNER Join States On Tickets.StateID = States.StateID 
    INNER Join Priorities On Tickets.priority = Priorities.PriorityID 
         WHERE Description Like '%SEARCHTEXT%' OR TicketNumber Like '%SEARCHTEXT%'
```

What I want is to expand above query with additional TicketNumbers that are the result of the query in the TicketActions table

```
    SELECT TicketNumber
    FROM dbo.ticketaction
    WHERE ActionDescription like '%SEARCHTEXT%'
```

So the result should be exact as the first query, but with added ticketnumbers that are found by the second query.

Any help would be very welcome, as I have really no idea how to approach this

Comment: That looks like a standard sub-query so add to your top query where TicketNumber in (SELECT TicketNumber
    FROM dbo.ticketaction
    WHERE ActionDescription like '%SEARCHTEXT%' ) or alternatively just add ticketaction to your top query and inner join on TicketNumber

Comment: I would do what Rich suggested.  At the end of your query put another OR and what he stated in his comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your literal question, it would be something like...

```
SELECT 
    tickets.TicketNumber, 
    tickets.Description,
    tickets.departmentname,
    tickets.devicename,
    tickets.creatorname,
    tickets.creationdate,
    tickets.ExecutionDate,
    tickets.closedate
    stateName,
    PriorityName,
    FullName,
FROM
           tickets
INNER Join Users      On Tickets.AssignedTo = Users.UserID
INNER Join States     On Tickets.StateID = States.StateID 
INNER Join Priorities On Tickets.priority = Priorities.PriorityID 
WHERE tickets.Description Like '%SEARCHTEXT%'
   OR tickets.TicketNumber Like '%SEARCHTEXT%'
   OR tickets.TicketNumber IN (SELECT TicketNumber
                                 FROM dbo.ticketaction
                                WHERE ActionDescription like '%SEARCHTEXT%'
                              )
```

A better solution, could be to use a `JOIN` on the `ticketAction` table

```
SELECT 
    tickets.TicketNumber, 
    tickets.Description,
    tickets.departmentname,
    tickets.devicename,
    tickets.creatorname,
    tickets.creationdate,
    tickets.ExecutionDate,
    tickets.closedate
    stateName,
    PriorityName,
    FullName,
FROM
           tickets
INNER JOIN Users        ON tickets.AssignedTo = Users.UserID
INNER JOIN States       ON tickets.StateID = States.StateID 
INNER JOIN Priorities   ON tickets.priority = Priorities.PriorityID 
INNER JOIN ticketAction ON ticket.TicketNumber = ticketAction.TicketNumber
WHERE tickets.Description Like '%SEARCHTEXT%'
   OR tickets.TicketNumber Like '%SEARCHTEXT%'
   OR ticketAction.ActionDescription LIKE '%SEARCHTEXT%'
```

*(That assumes every ticket has a ticketAction.  If that's not the case, use a `LEFT JOIN`)*

Or, `EXISTS()`...

```
SELECT 
    tickets.TicketNumber, 
    tickets.Description,
    tickets.departmentname,
    tickets.devicename,
    tickets.creatorname,
    tickets.creationdate,
    tickets.ExecutionDate,
    tickets.closedate
    stateName,
    PriorityName,
    FullName,
FROM
           tickets
INNER Join Users      On Tickets.AssignedTo = Users.UserID
INNER Join States     On Tickets.StateID = States.StateID 
INNER Join Priorities On Tickets.priority = Priorities.PriorityID 
WHERE tickets.Description Like '%SEARCHTEXT%'
   OR tickets.TicketNumber Like '%SEARCHTEXT%'
   OR EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM dbo.ticketaction
               WHERE ActionDescription like '%SEARCHTEXT%'
                 AND TicketNumber = tickets.TicketNumber
             )
```

Comment: Thanks Mat, both your solutions worked! This was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with a simple union? Below is sample code but may not be what you are exactly looking for.

[Union Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
SELECT tickets.TicketNumber
    ,tickets.Description
    ,tickets.departmentname
    ,tickets.devicename
    ,tickets.creatorname
    ,tickets.creationdate
    ,tickets.ExecutionDate
    ,tickets.closedate stateName
    ,PriorityName
    ,FullName
FROM tickets
INNER JOIN Users ON Tickets.AssignedTo = Users.UserID
INNER JOIN States ON Tickets.StateID = States.StateID
INNER JOIN Priorities ON Tickets.priority = Priorities.PriorityID
WHERE Description LIKE '%SEARCHTEXT%'
    OR TicketNumber LIKE '%SEARCHTEXT%'

UNION

SELECT t.TicketNumber
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
FROM dbo.ticketaction t
WHERE ActionDescription LIKE '%SEARCHTEXT%'
```

Comment: This is not what I wanted. I want to get the TicketNumbers that I get from the second query, and feed them as a Ticketnumber of the first query.

Comment: That's right Rich, But I can't get it to work, because the first Query already has joins...

Comment: :) read the first part wrong -- apologies, Rich commented with a workable solution.

Comment: @Karstieman you just need an extra inner join line i.e. 'inner join ticketaction on Tickets.TicketNumber = ticketaction.TicketNumber and an additional or clause for the 'ActionDescription like '%SEARCHTEXT%' ' bit. I'd also maybe add the table names for the PriorityName and FullName columns for clarity in the first query.